# How to add one variable at a time in regression model in SAS?

Tags: loops, sas, regression

I would like to run an ordinal logistic regression using either PROC LOGISTIC or PROC GENMOD in SAS, I have difficulty in programming the variable selection step, here is the variable selection method:

Add one variable to this model at a time, track the AIC score of that individual predictor, and then proceed to the next stage by adding another variable, track the AIC score, select model with lowest AIC, and so forth.

I don't know how to write a loop to run this selection procedure, also, how to get the AIC score for each step (output option?)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a `selection=stepwise` option in your `model` statement.

Please refer to: [Stepwise Logistic Regression](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect052.htm)and 
[Ordinal Regression](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect054.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I don't want to use stepwise method, and that's why I would like to use AIC score and program myself. Could you give more suggestions on the programming part? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure why you are averse to using the Stepwise option- from what you are saying it looks like you want to re-invent the wheel. Could you provide more details about what you are trying to do?